# NLog set custom logger namespace suffix when using ILoggerFactory / ILoggingBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nlog, ilogger

I have a third-party library that gives me the opportunity to connect `NLog` via an `ILoggerFactory` interface.
However, I would like to add a suffix to the logger namespace.

The following ExtensionMethod is currently used to inject `NLog`.

```cs
var factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddNLog());
```

Currently, a namespace looks like this:

`my.custom.library.class1`

`my.custom.library.class2`

`my.custom.library.with.inner.subclass`

However, I would like that behind every namespace there is e.g. `foo`

`my.custom.library.class1.foo`

`my.custom.library.class2.foo`

`my.custom.library.with.inner.subclass.foo`

Comment: I guess you could make a wrapper around `NLogLoggerProvider` that overrides `CreateLogger(string name)` so it injects the wanted suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix without any overloads.

```cs
var factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddNLogWithSuffix(_IpSuffix));
```

```cs
public static class LoggingBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AddNLogWithSuffix(this ILoggingBuilder builder, string loggerSuffix)
    {
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, NLogLoggerProviderWithSuffix>(_ => new NLogLoggerProviderWithSuffix(new NLogProviderOptions(), LogManager.LogFactory, loggerSuffix)));
    }
}

[ProviderAlias("NLog")]
public class NLogLoggerProviderWithSuffix : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly NLogLoggerProvider _NLogLoggerProvider;

    private readonly string _LoggerSuffix;

    /// <summary>New provider with options and a suffix</summary>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    /// <param name="logFactory">Optional isolated NLog LogFactory</param>
    /// <param name="loggerSuffix"></param>
    public NLogLoggerProviderWithSuffix(NLogProviderOptions options, LogFactory logFactory, string loggerSuffix)
    {
        _LoggerSuffix = loggerSuffix;
        _NLogLoggerProvider = new NLogLoggerProvider(options, logFactory);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _NLogLoggerProvider.Dispose();
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return _NLogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger($"{categoryName}.{_LoggerSuffix}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy that you found a solution.

Comment: Maybe mark your own answer as "the answer" :)